# opening file in python turtle graphics

Tags: python, file, turtle-graphics

```
import turtle
t=turtle.Turtle()
wn=turtle.Screen()
wn.setworldcoordinates(-300,-300,300,300)



directions = {             #dictionary of directions given in file.
'up': turtle.up,
'down': turtle.down
}


with open('dino.txt', 'r') as dino:
    for line in dino:
    line, pixel = line.split()       #split line into two different directions.

    if line in directions:#runs if within directions.
        directions[line](pixel)
    else:
        raise()             #raises error if not within directions.
```

I have this file titled "dino.txt" that has directions within it that are supposed to trace out a dinosaur in python turtle graphics. However i am having much trouble implementing a code that reads the file and traces out the image in the turtle graphics. The code i have written above opens the turtle graphics page but does not trace out anything. I was hoping someone on here could help me out or point out how exactly to implement a turtle graphic design in python from reading a text file. Thanks for any help/feedback.

here are the contents of the file "dino.txt":

```
UP 
-218 185 
DOWN 
-240 189 
-246 188 
-248 183 
-246 178 
-244 175 
-240 170 
-235 166 
-229 163 
-220 158 
-208 156 
-203 153 
-194 148 
-187 141 
-179 133 
-171 119 
-166 106 
-163 87 
-161 66 
-162 52 
-164 44 
-167 28 
-171 6 
-172 -15 
-171 -30 
-165 -46 
-156 -60 
-152 -67 
-152 -68 
UP 
-134 -61 
DOWN 
-145 -66 
-152 -78 
-152 -94 
-157 -109 
-157 -118 
-151 -128 
-146 -135 
-146 -136 
UP 
-97 -134 
DOWN 
-98 -138 
-97 -143 
-96 -157 
-96 -169 
-98 -183 
-104 -194 
-110 -203 
-114 -211 
-117 -220 
-120 -233 
-122 -243 
-123 -247 
-157 -248 
-157 -240 
-154 -234 
-154 -230 
-153 -229 
-149 -226 
-146 -223 
-145 -219 
-143 -214 
-142 -210 
-141 -203 
-139 -199 
-136 -192 
-132 -184 
-130 -179 
-132 -171 
-133 -162 
-134 -153 
-138 -145 
-143 -137 
-143 -132 
-142 -124 
-138 -112 
-134 -104 
-132 -102 
UP 
-97 -155 
DOWN 
-92 -151 
-91 -147 
-89 -142 
-89 -135 
-90 -129 
-90 -128 
UP 
-94 -170 
DOWN 
-83 -171 
-68 -174 
-47 -177 
-30 -172 
-15 -171
-11 -170 
UP 
12 -96 
DOWN 
9 -109
9 -127 
7 -140 
5 -157 
9 -164 
22 -176 
37 -204 
40 -209 
49 -220 
55 -229 
57 -235 
57 -238 
50 -239 
49 -241 
51 -248 
53 -249 
63 -245 
70 -243 
57 -249 
62 -250 
71 -250 
75 -250 
81 -250 
86 -248 
86 -242 
84 -232 
85 -226 
81 -221 
77 -211 
73 -205 
67 -196 
62 -187 
58 -180 
51 -171 
47 -164 
46 -153 
50 -141 
53 -130 
54 -124 
57 -112 
56 -102 
55 -98 
UP 
48 -164 
DOWN 
54 -158 
60 -146 
64 -136 
64 -131 
UP 
5 -152 
DOWN 
1 -150 
-4 -145 
-8 -138 
-14 -128 
-19 -119 
-17 -124 
UP 
21 -177 
DOWN 
14 -176 
7 -174 
-6 -174 
-14 -170 
-19 -166 
-20 -164 
UP 
-8 -173 
DOWN 
-8 -180 
-5 -189 
-4 -201 
-2 -211 
-1 -220 
-2 -231 
-5 -238 
-8 -241 
-9 -244 
-7 -249 
6 -247 
9 -248 
16 -247 
21 -246 
24 -241 
27 -234 
27 -226 
27 -219 
27 -209 
27 -202 
28 -193 
28 -188 
28 -184 
UP 
-60 -177 
DOWN 
-59 -186 
-57 -199 
-56 -211 
-59 -225 
-61 -233 
-65 -243 
-66 -245 
-73 -246 
-81 -246 
-84 -246 
-91 -245 
-91 -244 
-88 -231 
-87 -225 
-85 -218 
-85 -211 
-85 -203 
-85 -193 
-88 -185 
-89 -180 
-91 -175 
-92 -172 
-93 -170 
UP 
-154 -93 
DOWN 
-157 -87 
-162 -74 
-168 -66 
-172 -57 
-175 -49 
-178 -38 
-178 -26 
-178 -12 
-177 4 
-175 17 
-172 27 
-168 36 
-161 48 
-161 50 
UP 
-217 178 
DOWN 
-217 178 
-217 177 
-215 176 
-214 175 
-220 177 
-223 178 
-223 178 
-222 178 
UP 
-248 185 
DOWN 
-245 184 
-240 182 
-237 181 
-234 179 
-231 177 
-229 176 
-228 175 
-226 174 
-224 173 
-223 173 
-220 172 
-217 172 
-216 171 
-214 170 
-214 169 
UP 
-218 186 
DOWN 
-195 173 
-183 165 
-175 159 
-164 151 
-158 145 
-152 139 
-145 128 
-143 122 
-139 112 
-138 105 
-134 95 
-131 88 
-129 78 
-126 67 
-125 62 
-125 54 
-124 44 
-125 38 
-126 30 
-125 27 
-125 8 
-126 5 
-125 -9 
-122 -15 
-115 -25 
-109 -32 
-103 -39 
-95 -42 
-84 -45 
-72 -47 
-56 -48 
-41 -47 
-31 -46 
-18 -45 
-1 -44 
9 -43 
34 -45 
50 -52 
67 -61 
83 -68 
95 -80 
112 -97 
142 -115 
180 -132 
200 -146 
227 -159 
259 -175 
289 -185 
317 -189 
349 -190 
375 -191 
385 -192 
382 -196 
366 -199 
352 -204 
343 -204 
330 -205 
315 -209 
296 -212 
276 -214 
252 -208 
237 -202 
218 -197 
202 -193 
184 -187 
164 -179 
147 -173 
128 -168 
116 -164 
102 -160 
88 -158 
78 -159 
69 -162 
57 -164 
56 -165 
51 -165 
UP 
68 -144 
DOWN 
83 -143 
96 -141 
109 -139 
119 -146 
141 -150 
161 -155 
181 -163 
195 -169 
208 -179 
223 -187 
241 -191 
247 -193 
249 -194 
UP 
-6 -141 
DOWN 
-15 -146 
-29 -150 
-42 -154 
-51 -153 
-60 -152 
-60 -152 
UP 
-90 -134 
DOWN 
-85 -131 
-79 -128 
-78 -123 
-80 -115 
-82 -106 
-80 -101 
-76 -101 
UP 
-81 -132
DOWN 
-76 -130 
-71 -126 
-72 -124 
UP 
43 -118 
DOWN 
44 -125 
47 -135 
41 -156 
37 -160 
40 -166 
47 -171 
47 -171 
UP 
-106 -153 
DOWN 
-107 -167 
-106 -178 
-109 -192 
-114 -198 
-116 -201
```

Comment: Your code above isn't indented correctly -- in Python indentation equals function.  That may be a place to start before incorporating suggestions.  Compare your post with how your code appears in your file -- are they the same?  Or did something get confused in the process of showing us your work so far?

Answer (score 0):

This logic is wrong:

```
line, pixel = line.split()
```

If the data is as show in the edited version of your question, consider:

```
data = line.rstrip().split()
```

you only have two cases, either the length of list data is 1, meaning you have a direction like UP or DOWN in `data[0]`, or the length of list data is 2, meaning you have the arguments for a `goto()` (after you first convert the two strings to integers).  That's it.

If the data is more free form as show in your original post, then you need to process the data one token at a time.  Pull off one data item and convert it via `int()` under a `try` clause.  If it succeeds, read the next data item as an int and do a `goto()` using both, otherwise treat the current data item as a direction in the `except` clause since it's clearly not an int

Errors to check for include:  numbers don't correctly convert to integers; direction not found in `directions` dictionary.

Other things to consider:  change your `directions` keys to uppercase to match the data in the file or explicitly control the case yourself; if you use `setworldcoordinates()` this way, you may skew the aspect ratio of the image -- make your window square to begin with (whatever size) using `wn.setup(size, size)`; your maximum virtual coordinate of 300 falls short of your data: 385.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the input and corrections, I appreciate it. Like the commenter below mentioned however, substituting in "line, pixel = line.split()" does not trace anything for me and raises an error so not sure why its not working; if you could comment again how you were able to trace out the image exactly that would be much appreciated. Also when you said that the numbers in the file do not correctly convert to integers I'm not sure exactly what that entails or how to fix that in my dictionary (very new to coding). Thanks again!

Comment: @emordnilap, my code was not meant to solve your problem, just point out where trouble begins.  My answer outlines how you might proceed.  Your `raise()` code is broken so I'd comment it out until you've got the basics working and then revisit it.  You haven't followed up about the format of your data, is it line by line as currently shown or a blob as in your original post?  My answer isn't a quick fix but some suggestions to get you moving forward.  I'm not saying your numbers won't convert to integers, just that if you add error checking, that's an obvious test.  Ditto checking dict keys.

Comment: I changed my original data format to emulate the line by line data format shown above